# Passing data when query returns value and No "EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN" (Oracle 11g)

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have  created a procedure for updating my `t_ritm` table. First I have select `rrcd_qnty` (which is my product quantity) of a product id from `t_rrcd` table. Then I update the  `rrcd_qnty` value in `t_ritm` table.

Here is my procedure:

```
procedure update_ritm_new_rate(p_oid in varchar2, p_ritm_rate in varchar2, p_euser in varchar2)
is
nrate varchar2(4);
begin
    SELECT rrcd_rate into nrate 
    FROM (select oid, t_rrcd.rrcd_rate 
           from t_rrcd 
           where rrcd_ritm= p_oid 
           ORDER BY oid DESC ) 
    WHERE rownum <= 1 
    ORDER BY rownum DESC ;  
EXCEPTION  
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN  nrate := 0; 


    update t_ritm 
    set ritm_rate = nrate, euser = p_euser, edat = sysdate  
    where oid = p_oid;
    commit;
end update_ritm_new_rate;
```

Some of my product id Quantity was `null`. so I was getting `No_Data_Found`  error. But when and which product id has Quantity value  they were successfully updating. For avoiding  `No_Data_Found`  I used `EXCEPTION  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN  nrate := 0;`  which solved my `no_Data_Found` error. But when product id has quantity value they were not updating.

I had search lot of for this issue but not get good solution. What should be the best practice for avoiding `No_Data_Found` error?  Could I pass my value if I don't get any `No_Data_Found` error?

thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because - if your `SELECT` returns something, it never reaches `UPDATE` as it is *hidden* behind the `EXCEPTION` handler.

Therefore, enclose it (`SELECT`) into its own `BEGIN-END` block, and put `UPDATE` out of it so that it is executed with whichever `NRATE` value is used.

```
PROCEDURE update_ritm_new_rate (p_oid         IN VARCHAR2,
                                p_ritm_rate   IN VARCHAR2,
                                p_euser       IN VARCHAR2)
IS
   nrate   VARCHAR2 (4);
BEGIN
   BEGIN                                               --> this
        SELECT rrcd_rate
          INTO nrate
          FROM (  SELECT oid, t_rrcd.rrcd_rate
                    FROM t_rrcd
                   WHERE rrcd_ritm = p_oid
                ORDER BY oid DESC)
         WHERE ROWNUM <= 1
      ORDER BY ROWNUM DESC;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
      THEN
         nrate := 0;
   END;                                               --> this

   UPDATE t_ritm
      SET ritm_rate = nrate, euser = p_euser, edat = SYSDATE
    WHERE oid = p_oid;

   COMMIT;
END update_ritm_new_rate;
```

Comment: Thank You. you shaved my time. :) 3

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by adding **EXCEPTION  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN  nrate := 0;** after the update query.

```
procedure update_ritm_new_rate(p_oid in varchar2, p_ritm_rate in varchar2, p_euser in varchar2)
is
nrate varchar2(4);
begin
    SELECT rrcd_rate into nrate FROM (select oid, t_rrcd.rrcd_rate  from t_rrcd where rrcd_ritm= p_oid ORDER BY oid DESC ) 
    WHERE rownum <= 1 ORDER BY rownum DESC ;  

    update t_ritm set ritm_rate = nrate, euser = p_euser, edat = sysdate  where oid = p_oid;
    commit;

    EXCEPTION  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN  nrate := 0;
end update_ritm_new_rate;
```

Comment: That would be wrong, because you won't UPDATE if you hit the exception. See my example.

Comment: Yes, You are Right I have fixed it but mine was working perfectly what I need. Thanks again

Comment: If you say so, why should I worry? However, you could have used `then null;` because setting NRATE to 0 doesn't change anything at all. OK then, I'm glad you solved the problem.